# Breakpoints in callbacks are not hit in Python in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, callback

I am new to Python and doing some development on Windows using `Python 3.7 + Anaconda + VS Code`. Now when I debug my Python program by hitting F5 with a debug configuraiton like this :

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode":false,
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "PATH\\TO\\PYTHON"}
    }
```

I discovered that the breakpoints I placed in the callback functions are not hit, while the "normal" breakpoints are. The callbacks are definitely called because I can see the output from the terminal. It should be noted that only callbacks from external packages are not paused by the breakpoints. The callback functions that I created myself do not have this kind of problem. The function can be paused if I place a line `breakpoint()` but obviously it makes the debug routine very clumsy.

I have searched the web but didn't have too many references of this problem. Anyone happenes to see  this before?

UPDATE:

Here I have attached some code and steps I used when launching and debugging. The code looks like this:

```
class MyDerivedClass(BaseClassOfExternalPackage):
def __init__(self, settings : ExternalPackageSetting):
    if settings:
        super(MyDerivedClass, self).__init__(settings)                  

def onConnect(self, msg):
    # breakpoint()
    self.write_log("Connect success. " + msg)
```

And the function `onConnect` is a callback defined in the `BaseClassOfExternalPackage` from external package. So the breakpoint I put in the `self.write_log` line, never gets hit although the log is written successfully. And if I uncomment the `breakpoint` line, the program is paused successfully.

How I debug the program: I click the side-bar of VS-code to select the python executable that I set for this conda env. And the configuration part `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "PATH\\TO\\PYTHON"}`, `PATH\\TO\\PYTHON` is no conda env path, but the root folder of my program (if I don't set it like this it won't import the modules I write)

Comment: do you have a small example with the behavior? Have you placed the breakpoint in the correct version of the file in case you use virtual environments

Comment: @rioV8 like I said only callbacks defined in external packages developed by other teams of ours (though from multiple unrelated packages) have this problem, so it's not easy to put a clear example code here. And what do you mean the curent version of the file? You mean the .py source files? I specified the python executable in side-bar of VS-code. I activated the conda env in an external conda terminal before I hit F5 because in VS-code the python debug console doesn't recognize command conda.

Comment: I don't use `conda` but the `venv` python module and have no problems with python debugging. What is your project directory layout and where is your code and the other modules. It should be possible to describe a setup with 2-line functions and 2 modules (yours and theirs)

Comment: @rioV8 I have added some code, please have a look at. Thank you very much!

Comment: First remark: don't use `super` it will give you troubles if you use multiple inheritance, always fully qualify the method you want from which Base class: `BaseClass.method(self, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: I will try this setup and see if it debugs in a non conda environment

Comment: running from a venv virtual environment and the BaseClass module is a subdir of the workspace root I have no problem hitting a breakpoint in the override/callback method of the child class

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for your input. I'll try with a non-conda environment and see how it goes

Comment: I followed your guide, add breakpoint() to callback call and debugger worked. Thank you!